# VS Code Explorer is not visible after clicking on git icon

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code Explorer is not visible after clicking on git icon. i can see other option in right panel but explorer option is invisible .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCmgU.png)

Comment: Try CTRL + SHIFT + E to open it. Also try closing and re-opening VS Code.

Comment: You probably moved the Explorer and its icon somewhere.  Use the `view: Reset View Locations` command.

Comment: It happens to me as well. I think an extension is breaking this.  I use vscode on multiple computers and this behavior only occurs on a computer which has unique extensions installed.  Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find it in view/Explorer or simply use ctrl+shift+e .

also check for the latest version of vscode

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please right-click on the activity bar and make sure "Explorer" is checked.